# Laravel Echo Client cannot be authenticated

Tags: laravel, laravel-echo

I see this question has been asked multiple times, but non of the answers are working so I am asking for help and some insight with it.

I am using laravel echo and redis for broadcasting events. My laravel echo server stars up nicely, redis is running nicely.

When I reload my webpage I get this error in the laravel-echo server terminal:

```
⚠ [4:49:19 PM] - qg4WSWl5YusQY8hJAAAA could not be authenticated to private-test-channel.1
{"error":"Unauthenticated."}
Client can not be authenticated, got HTTP status 401
```

and I have gone back and forth with that to do with it and nothings helps with it.

Here is my `app.js`

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo";

window.Echo = new Echo({
  broadcaster: 'socket.io',
  host: window.location.hostname + ':6001'
});
```

Here is my `echo.js`

```
  window.Echo.private('test-channel.{{Auth::user()->id}}')
    .listen('EventName', function(event) {
      console.log('data', event);
  });
```

My `BroadcastServiceProvider`

```
public function boot()
{
  //broadcast routes middleware
  Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth', 'web']]);

  /*
  * Authenticate the user's personal channel...
  */
  Broadcast::channel('App.User.*', function ($user, $userId) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $userId;
  });

  //require all base channels
  require base_path('routes/channels.php');
}
```

this is my larave-echo-server.json

```
{
    "authHost": "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [
        {
            "appId": "570453f474365cc8",
            "key": "4baec74e662696009e7857e49d3364c4"
        }
    ],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {},
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": "",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": ""
}
```

When I fire my event, then I  get the event in the console, but the user cannot be authenticated for some reason and I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Got any solutions , I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen in routes/channels.php for permission?

this is the link for explanation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/broadcasting#authorizing-channels 
I see that you have put `BroadcastServiceProvider`

```
Broadcast::channel('App.User.*', function ($user, $userId) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $userId;
  });
```

But in routes/channels.php default command is:

```
Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
```

maybe it is creating some conflict or problem

Comment: have you delete the code inside BroadcastServiceProvider and put permission in channels.php  as documentation say? can you edit with channels.php?
Have you import 
<script src="//{{ Request::getHost() }}:6001/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
as documentation say https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/broadcasting#configuration ?

Comment: Can you edit question with channels.php and BroadcastServiceProvider without channel?
I think the problem is the name of Broadcast::channel(). it should be: Broadcast::channel(test-channel.{id})